# Read Certain Value from Input File

Tags: shell, input, stream

I want to code a shell script which stores a value from an input file with a certain key word.

The structure of my input file is:

```
text \n 
text \n
key_word = value \n
text \n
text \n
```

How can I read that value?

Comment: Please provide us with what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

In grep ^ indicates start of line. Something like this should work:

```
grep ^key_word filename | awk -F"=" '{ print $2}'
```

Comment: awk alone can handle this: `awk -F= '/^key_word/ {print $2}' filename`.